# Get class as resource stream

Tags: java, reflection, stream

I know that you can get a file in your jar with

```
InputStream resource = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("com/foo/bar.txt");
```

Is it possible to do that with classes also, with something like:

```
InputStream yourclass = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("com/foo/Clazz.class");
```

Edit: I checked it, and the seccond example does work. It just returns `null`. I am wondering if there is something that would do what the seccond example should.

Comment: Yes, based on your above code, it should work just fine.

Comment: Regarding the returning null, it may be [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522235/getsystemresourceasstream-returns-null).

Comment: Can you post that as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Agree with code is fine. It's better to check if the path `"com/foo/Clazz.class"` is correct.