# Java ClassLoader.getResource(String name) finds directory but no files in it

Tags: java, resources, classloader, module-info

in my maven project, the resources folder look like this:

- resources

  - images

    - TestImage.png

If I call

```
System.out.println(MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images"));
```

I get "file:/C:/Users/XYZXYZ/IdeaProjects/projectName/core/target/classes/images/"

If I add the file name like this:

```
System.out.println(MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images/TestImage.png"));
```

I get "null". How is this possible? What happens here?

Edit: I noticed that it works (does not give null anymore), as soon as I delete my module-info.java
Problem: I need my module-info.java. Any tips?

Comment: do you have "TestImage.png" in folder "target/classes/images/"?

Comment: @guleryuz Yes, I do.

Comment: You probably don't. My guess is that you have `testImage.png`, or `TestImage.png.png`, or `TestImage.PNG`, or something like that.

Comment: what this prints `System.out.println(MainClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("images\\TestImage.png"));` ?

Comment: @guleryuz It prints "null" aswell.

Comment: @JB Nizet The name is correct. I checked that 3 times and in the end copied the name just to make sure.

Comment: What is the output of `dir C:/Users/XYZXYZ/IdeaProjects/projectName/core/target/classes/images/`?

Comment: @JBNizet where should I put "dir C:/Users ..." ?

Comment: In your command line window. Where you execute commands.

Comment: 30.11.2019  10:37    <DIR>          .
30.11.2019  10:37    <DIR>          ..
03.06.2019  21:59            41.229 TestImage.png

Comment: @JBNizet When I delete my module-info.java, it works, can I add anything to my module-info in order to make it work then aswell?

Comment: I know nothing about modules, sorry.

Comment: @JBNizet The question seems to be completely related to the introduction of Java module system with the `module-info.java` class file as pointed by the OP. @TimB. The difference in the execution could be a result of the `ClassLoader` implementation change with respect to the module system as pointed out in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494112/classloaders-hierarchy-in-java-9). One can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694600/) and the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) for better understanding.