# getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream() not work in modular java project (openjdk 11)?

Tags: java, maven, classloader, java-11, java-module

this is a **maven project**, and have one image in **resources directory**:

```
├─ src
   ├─ main
       ├─ java
       └─ resources  
          └─imgs
            └─logo.png
```

Code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InputStream stream = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/imgs/logo.png");
        InputStream stream1 = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("imgs/logo.png");
        System.out.println(stream == null ? "stream is null!" : "stream is not null!");
        System.out.println(stream1 == null ? "stream1 is null!" : "stream1 is not null!");
    }
}
```

when I **add** `module-info.java` to project, will print:

```
stream is null!
stream1 is null!
```

but when I **remove** `module-info.java` from project, will print:

```
stream is null!
stream1 is not null!
```

why? and how to use `ClassLoader` to load resources in modular java project?

Comment: Related - [Classloaders hierarchy in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46494112/classloaders-hierarchy-in-java-9)

Comment: When you get resource from ClassLoader, you are already starting from root, so you shouldn't use / in front, so the second one is correct. module is another story.

Answer (score 4):

Resources should be loaded over the `Test.class`, not its ClassLoader. By loading the resource over the class, you establish a context (JAR, module, dependencies) for where the resource is located.

For resources **in the same package**, use a relative path:

```
Test.class.getResource("logo.png")
```

If the qualified name of Test is `org.foo.Test`, it would lookup the resource in `org/foo/logo.png` in the JAR (or in the resources folder, before building the JAR).

For resources **in the same module**, use an absolute path, starting with a slash:

```
Test.class.getResource("/logo.png")
```

^ this is what you want to use most of the time.

**There's no need to go over the classloader**. I see this often when developers are unaware of how to properly address a resource, and load the resource with a *relative path* but *over the classloader*, which works most of the time but not very well with modular projects/classloaders such as Java9 and OSGI.

Comment: I know `Test.class.getResource("/logo.png")` this way to get resources, but I want to know how to use `ClassLoader` to load resources.

Comment: @Guo If you want to use a ClassLoader you can look at the source code of `getResourceAsStream` in the OpenJDK source code: https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L2614

Comment: The ClassLoader API docs is a better resource, in particular the statement that it only find resources in packages of named modules then the package is opened unconditionally.  Class::getResourceAsStream is the right API for code in a module to open resources in its own module.