# Which classloader loades Array class in Java?

Tags: java, classloader

The following code prints the classloader of 4 arrays.
My question is:

1. Why classloader of array is different?
2. Does output `null` have the same meaning?

```
/**
 * output:
 * null
 * sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2
 * null
 * null
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = new String[2];
        System.out.println(strings.getClass().getClassLoader()); // ①

        Test[] tests = new Test[2];
        System.out.println(tests.getClass().getClassLoader()); // ②

        int[] ints = new int[2];
        System.out.println(ints.getClass().getClassLoader()); // ③

        Integer[] integers = new Integer[2];
        System.out.println(integers.getClass().getClassLoader()); // ④
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Null represents the bootstrap class loader here. See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader

Answer (score 1):

A minimal subset of the core JDK classes are loaded using the boot class loader, which is represented as `null`.

Other classes are then loaded with the `AppClassLoader`. For more info check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46494370/1751640) answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test[] tests = new Test[2];
```

This is your own class. It was loaded by `Launcher$AppClassLoader`.

But others, they belong to the `java.lang.*` package. They were loaded by `bootstrapClassLoader`.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.boot.class.path"));
```

You can try it; it can get all paths by `BootStrapClassLoader`.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of the classloader is to return the class loader for the class which loads classes into memory dynamically.

Now, answer to your questions are:

1. Why the classloader of the array is different? 
   **Ans:** Because it is being called by the **different classloaders** and **not** all classes are being loaded by **a single ClassLoader**.
2. Does output null have the same meaning?
   **Ans:** `Null` means this class was loaded by **the bootstrap class loader** which means `a primitive type or void`.
   And A Bootstrap Classloader is a **Machine code** that kickstarts the operation when the **JVM calls it**. It is not a java class. Its job is to load the first **pure Java ClassLoader**. Bootstrap ClassLoader loads classes from the location rt.jar. Bootstrap ClassLoader doesn’t have any parent ClassLoaders. It is also called as the Primordial ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

After reading JVM specification and [doc of ClassLoader.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), I found the answer.

The output `null` have different meaning.

- output of ① `null` means **boostrap class loader**
- output of ③ `null` means **no class loader**
- output of ④ `null` means **boostrap class loader**

> From [doc of ClassLoader.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html):
> Class objects for array classes are not created by class loaders, but are created automatically as required by the Java runtime. **The class loader for an array class, as returned by Class.getClassLoader() is the same as the class loader for its element type; if the element type is a primitive type, then the array class has no class loader**.

> From [JVM specification 5.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):
> If C is not an array class, it is created by loading a binary representation of C using a class loader. **Array classes do not have an external binary representation; they are created by the Java Virtual Machine rather than by a class loader**.

> From [JVM specification 5.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3.3):
>
> 1. If the component type is a reference type, the algorithm of this section is applied recursively using class loader L in order to load and thereby create the component type of C.
> 2. The Java Virtual Machine creates a new array class with the indicated component type and number of dimensions.
>    **If the component type is a reference type, C is marked as having been defined by the defining class loader of the component type. Otherwise, C is marked as having been defined by the bootstrap class loader**.
>    In any case, the Java Virtual Machine then records that L is an initiating loader for C.