# SpringBoot Jar cannot load a TrueType Font

Tags: java, spring-boot, fonts

I discovered a strange behavior when I want to use a Font, that is included in the springboot fat jar. When running tests on my local machine, which loads a Font from the `/resources` directory, it works perfectly. But if I build an app with maven and run it from the terminal, then I will receive:

```
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
at java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1000)
at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:877)
```

I tried to find a solution and did the following:

- using different Fonts (sometimes with another error about a damaged table or sth.)
- built various versions of docker openjdk containers to test behavior
- build a ubuntu container, installed openjdk
- used a debian image, installed fc-cache and made the Font available via

  - `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/europlate`
  - `fc-cache -f -v`
- created a temp-File, just to be sure, that there is no access problem from within the jar.
- ran the application from my terminal, where loading the font fails, too
- using the font works on Editors, and even when the app runs from the IDE (no test)

The method:

```java
     public Font getFont() throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        File f = File.createTempFile("dang", "tmp");
        assert f != null;
        f.delete();
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, classLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("EuroPlate.ttf"));
        font.deriveFont(105f);
        System.out.println(font.getFontName());
        return font;
    }
```

EDIT:
IDE runs application -> works

Terminal runs application -> fails

Stacktrace:

```java
java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1183)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1052)
    at components.NumberPlateUtility.getFont(NumberPlateUtility.java:81)
    at components.NumberPlateUtility.completeImage(NumberPlateUtility.java:173)
    at main.NumberplateClientCommands.one(NumberplateClientCommands.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:223)
    at org.springframework.shell.Shell.evaluate(Shell.java:169)
    at org.springframework.shell.Shell.run(Shell.java:134)
    at org.springframework.shell.jline.InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.run(InteractiveShellApplicationRunner.java:84)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:783)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:773)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

The repository: https://github.com/Semo/numberplate_generator.git

Comment: Are you using the same jdk `openjdk` in development environment?

Comment: @Malathi Well, I tried so many, that I don't know. I will make sure right now and tell the result. RESULT: Same issue, though same versions.

Comment: What are you trying to _do_ with the font? It's extremely uncommon for a Boot application to manipulate a font (as opposed to, for example, serving it to clients to use in the browser).

Comment: You meant that you use openjdk x without docker and use the same openjdk x version with docker build. And you get the issue in the dockerised container and not in the environment without docker. Is that right?

Comment: @chrylis using the font in the backend to render a String into an image and send it to a webservice for further use.

Comment: @Malathi right, excepting that I NOW found out, that the issue occurs in both places containerized/locally, when running the app straight from the terminal without any help from an IDE via `java -jar app.jar`. I pointed that out in my adapted question.

Comment: Can you extract the jar and see if it has the font?

Comment: @Malathi Yes. It is in the root of BOOT-INF/classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will work:

```java
public Font getFont() throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        File f = File.createTempFile("dang", "tmp");
        assert f != null;
        f.delete();
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, classLoader.getResourceAsStream("EuroPlate.ttf"));
        font.deriveFont(105f);
        System.out.println(font.getFontName());
        return font;
    }
```

Note the change in `classLoader.getResourceAsStream`. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2523252/1237402) for more explanation.